# Could not execute the command "gxexec"

Tags: genexus

https://i.stack.imgur.com/89swT.png

I get these errors from time to time when running the project.

The files are there and it should work.

Comment: You should try to put the entire error log, as the image isn't showing the filenames...

Comment: Welcome to [so], which is not a free debugging service. Have a [tour], learn [ask]. Help others help you, try to include all relevant details and include a [mcve].

Comment: @SandroMagrinelliVianna  the files are always diffrent, i very the folder for each one and they're there

Comment: @AndreiAvram By this random behavior, I'm suspecting that your antivirus/firewall is blocking some execution, or even some files, can you try to disable it and see if it behave as it should?